# CraftCMS with Redis: Failed to open redis DB connection (tcp://:, database=): 0 - Failed to parse address ":"

Tags: server, redis, craftcms

I have `yii2` and `yii2-redis` installed on a CraftCMS project, but when I fire up the project, I get an error message that reads:

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
> Failed to open redis DB connection (tcp://:, database=): 0 - Failed to parse address ":"
> Error Info: Failed to parse address ":"

I'm not quite sure what to do with this error. In my .env file, I put in:

```
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PORT=3306
REDIS_PASSWORD=
REDIS_KEY_PREFIX=craft
```

But that only yielded a different error:

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
> Failed to open redis DB connection (tcp://:3306, database=): 0 - php_network_getaddresses:
> getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> Error Info: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Help?

Additional context: I didn't set up the build for this project, so I more or less inherited this Redis setup.

**Update:**
I went and dug into the config file for the Redis setup and found a misnaming between the .env variables and what was present in the .env file. Now I'm getting a completely different error:

> "Received illegal data from redis: Redis command was: SELECT 0"

Comment: Have you tried using REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1?  Is the translating from environment variables to arguments part of the framework or are you doing that?  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis suggest this is something you might be implementing.  Can you share the relevant code with us?

Comment: Hey Allan! Solid points. After reading what you wrote, I went and dug into the config file for the Redis setup and found a misnaming between the .env variables and what was present in the .env file. 

Now I'm getting a completely different error: 

"Received illegal data from redis:
Redis command was: SELECT 0"

Comment: Does that command work with redis-cli?  It will also allow you to double check the port (3306 is usually MySQL; 6379 is the default Redis port).

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/select says "When using Redis Cluster, the SELECT command cannot be used" which might be relevant for you.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and time, Allan. Turns out it was a silly mistake on my part - I'd accidentally deleted the Redis database. Creating a new one fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Please check that your [configuration matches](http://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis) the environment variables you use.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'd deleted the Redis database (don't remember how or when), so creating a new one (with the correct .env variables set) fixed the problem immediately.

Whew.